Can't rotate a model matrix without it moving from origin
I am having a difficult time trying to rotate a model which is located at 0,0,0 position.
Here is the model class that sets this up:
import { mat4, vec3 } from "gl-matrix";

export class Model {
  constructor(yaw, pitch, roll, position) {
    this.mat = mat4.create();
    
    // Convert degrees to radians
    this.yaw = this.#degToRad(yaw);
    this.pitch = this.#degToRad(pitch);
    this.roll = this.#degToRad(roll);
    this.position = position;

    this.#create();
  }

  #degToRad(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
  }

  #create() {
    mat4.identity(this.mat);
    mat4.scale(this.mat, this.mat, vec3.fromValues(1, 1, 1));  // Apply scaling
    mat4.rotateX(this.mat, this.mat, this.pitch);  // Rotate around X-axis (pitch)
    mat4.rotateY(this.mat, this.mat, this.yaw);    // Rotate around Y-axis (yaw)
    mat4.rotateZ(this.mat, this.mat, this.roll);   // Rotate around Z-axis (roll)

    console.log(this.mat);
  }
}

If I initialize with the properties:
    const model = new Model(
      0,                      // yaw
      0,                   // pitch
      0,                      // roll
      vec3.fromValues(0,0,0)  // position
    );

The model is centered in view as expected. When I set a pitch or yaw, the model appears to move
Here is an example of what it looks like when the pitch is -20 degrees

I am not sure what I am missing as the order of operations for matrix calculations seem to be correct.
For clarity, here is how the view is calculated:
import { mat4, vec3 } from "gl-matrix";

export class View {
  constructor(cameraPos, targetPos) {
    this.cameraPos = cameraPos;
    this.targetPos = targetPos;

    // forward
    this.forwardVector = vec3.create();
    vec3.subtract(this.forwardVector, this.targetPos, this.cameraPos);
    vec3.normalize(this.forwardVector, this.forwardVector);
    
    // right
    this.rightVector = vec3.create();
    vec3.cross(this.rightVector, this.forwardVector, [0, 1, 0]);
    vec3.normalize(this.rightVector, this.rightVector);
    
    // up
    this.upVector = vec3.create();
    vec3.cross(this.upVector, this.rightVector, this.forwardVector);

    this.mat = mat4.create();

    this.#newViewMatrix();
  }

  #newViewMatrix() {
    mat4.lookAt(this.mat, this.cameraPos, this.targetPos, this.upVector);
  }
}


There is a lot going on there, I highly recommend simplifying down to doing a rotation on a single axis such as the y axis. And setting the camera to a fixed position using only the lookat function to lookat the origin.  Rotations are always around the origin so either the model isn't at the origin to start with, or it is getting translated in one of the calculations. Simplifying things down will help clarify where and what the issue is.
